# Multithreading with Anonymous inner classes

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, anonymous-inner-class

Why output not the "1,2,3,4,5" ? Maybe multiple threads gets instance variable at the same time ? or it's about outer class variable is accessed from inner class methods ?

```
public class Test {

        int i;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Test t = new Test();
            for (t.i = 1; t.i <= 5; t.i++) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        System.out.println(t.i);

                    }
                }).start();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of executing it concurrently if you need to get a serial output? Your task seems inherently sequential, so do it in the main thread without spawning reader threads.

Comment: I want to inject each index to separate thread. I need it for database pagination, I use each index for page and execute multiple threads with different pages.